# Get text after "pid=" and before " ("

Tags: php, ubuntu

I'm using php to execute a command to run a game server that outputs a string. I need to parse the pid out of the string so that I can save it and then use it to kill the process at a later date.

```
"...server daemon started with pid=6849 (parent=6848)."
```

So It would return **6849**.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: This is an obvious job for `preg_match()`. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A regular expression for example?

Comment: Honestly I have tried nothing, regular expressions confuse me profusely and I was hoping somebody could spell out this problem in a simple example to help me better understand it.

Comment: @user1024370 - Why not read up about regular expressions? They are very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/pid=(\d+)/', $string, $matches) {
    $pid = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great! I think you were missing another ')' though. Can you explain how you came up with that regex? I can see whats going on with the /pid=, but im not sure what the (\d+)/ is doing. Also how does it know to end at the space?

Comment: The `\d+` says 1 or more digits (numbers) so that's how it knows to end at the space, because it's not a number. The parens are to capture the digits and put them in `$matches`.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks Afro Samurai!